# DatetimeType in Symfony Form: error validating sending a POST request manually

Tags: forms, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm developing a REST API with Symfony and FOS Rest bundle. One of my entities has a date field. I'm also doing test with behat, my problem is when I try to test the post action of this action I always get a 400 error due to the validation of the Datetime field.
Here's the field definition:

```
           ->add(
                'scheduledAt', DateTimeType::class, [
                'label' => 'fields.scheduled_at',
                'required' => false,
                'format' => 'Y-m-d h:i'
            ])
```

And here's the behat test:

```
When I send a POST request to "/api/cases/1/actions" with body:
      """
      {
          "comments": "Comments 3",
          "action": 1,
          "scheduledAt": "2017-01-01 17:00:00"
      }
      """
```

This always end up with this 400 response

```
{
"code":400,
"message":"Validation Failed",
"errors":{"children":{"comments":[],"scheduledAt":{"errors":["This value is not valid."],"children":{"date":{"children":{"year":[],"month":[],"day":[]}},"time":{"children":{"hour":[],"minute":[]}}}},"action":[]}}}
```

Comment: If your submit data for `scheduledAt` is a single text, when adding this field, the option `widget` must be `single_text`. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#widget

Comment: I did that but same result @PigBall

Comment: Share with us action method body please.

Comment: @michail_w action is post, it's a post request done by the guzzle client (using behat). its not a real form. It works fine for the rest of the fields, its just datetime wich doesnt

Comment: Please share with us code of controller action method...

Answer (score 1):

Please change format to `'format' => 'Y-m-d h:i:s'`, if you want to pass the request, or send through POST date without seconds part.

Comment: I did that and add the 'widget' => 'single_text' option but same result. The date format is ok this way right? 'Y-m-d h:i' Im sending "2017-01-01 17:00"

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, it's in the date format, should be like this:

```
'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'
```

Comment: the option widget must be single_text too

Comment: in the section https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#format see the link to view the date/time formats or go here: http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime#TOC-Date-Time-Format-Syntax